# Why does the mouse always move to the bottom left?

Tags: windows-7, mouse

In the course of doing stuff on the computer, the mouse always moves, by itself, to the bottom left of the screen - I'd say several times in the course of an hour.  I thought this might be an issue with the driver, so I re-installed the driver, but the problem continued.  Then thinking that the mouse is faulty, I replaced my Microsoft Wheel Mouse with a Dell mouse.  The problem still continues.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: is this a slow gradual move, or a fast jump?

Comment: @NateKoppenhaver Fast jump.

Comment: Your mouse battery is going dead.  If it's a corded mouse, the cable has broken where it enters the mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you on a laptop? The trackpad or thumb mouse may be faulty. See if you can disable it in the Control Panel or its configuration application.

Comment: This solution was a great idea, but ultimately it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a mousepad, it could be the culprit. Mousepads with pictures can make your mouse pointer move alone or make your mouse pointer "jump" non-smoothly when you move it. The best mousepads for me are with solid colors.

Comment: It was actually the touchscreen of my laptop.  I disabled the Tablet PC service and all is good now.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem on my Windows XP PC with a Pentium 4 processor; I assume it is because of the speaker's magnetic effect on the mouse.
I have tried lot of fixes, but the problem continues. I suggest to keep the mouse away from your speakers if you have them

Comment: Which kind of mouse are you using? That is strange.

Comment: Maybe Logitech or Microsoft. But it happens..I thought it to be an OS problem but in other PCs also I've marked that.In laptop never faced such a problem.

Comment: It is not due to the speaker's magnetic field.