# Why does the mouse icon look like this and jump to the bottom-left corner of the screen?

Tags: windows-7, mouse

My mouse frequently jumps to the bottom left of the [screen](https://superuser.com/questions/359612/why-does-the-mouse-always-move-to-the-bottom-left).

When it does so, the cursor briefly turns into this (zoom type thing):

[image]

Can someone tell me what application this icon is from?  Perhaps by identifying the icon I can figure out why the mouse jumps to the bottom left all the time.

Comment: Looks like the stylus/touch pointer + the standard waiting spinner? I believe the rules are that visual identification of icons, toolbars, etc. are not valid questions for SU (because you can't search for them later).

Comment: He wants to know WHY the icon jumps to the bottom of the screen and so is looking for help figuring that out. His question is not simply an "identify this" question. Though it should be reworded to clarify that.

Comment: Have you checked your system logs around when the cursor jumps to see if there are any common reports from around those times?

Comment: @music2myear Whoever deleted an answer was onto something with the suggestion that it could be the touchscreen or the stylus.  I disabled the Tablet PC Input Service and so far, so good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a touchscreen laptop (tablet) running windows 7.

I had troubles similar to this with my wife's HP touchscreen laptop and they ended up replacing several parts of the device. It was primarily related to an improperly cooled AMD CPU, but the video system was messed up as well.

But I'm not sure your's is the same issue. Unfortunately, it's difficult to be sure.

It appeared to me, when I had the similar issue, that the touch screen itself was reporting incorrect touches, always at the same place. The cursor would give a grey circle which, as techie007 noted, indicates a touch-hold interaction which allows you to bring up context menus, like a right-click would do when using a mouse, along with the little star.

The star icon to the lower right indicates stylus input. The fact that you're getting this star when your stylus is holstered indicates the touchscreen itself (probably Wacom) is registering false touches.

You may try installing or reinstalling the most recent service pack, making sure your drivers (including the touch screen) are up to date, and making sure you've got the most recent windows updates. If the issue persists after doing all this, I'd contact the manufacturer, if the laptop is still under warranty.

Comment: The right-click when you hold animates a large grey circle around your "tip" that you have to wait for before release (to 'confirm' the right-click).

Comment: You're right. Editing.

Comment: You are right - this is a touchscreen (with a stylus) laptop.  But I never use it that way. And the stylus is its holding bay.

How do I turn off this functionality?

Comment: I disabled the Tablet PC Input Service and so far, so good